# Append Var to URL in PHP

Tags: php, hyperlink, formatting

I can't seem to get this to work...what I have is a link being auto-generated to send out in an email, and I need to be able to append the user's email address to the URL, but I can't seem to get it formatted correctly.  Here's what I have:

```
href=\"http://example.com/unsubscribe/\" . $email . \"\"
```

Where the resulting link in the user's email should be

```
http://example.com/unsubscribe/myemail@myemail.com
```

The way the unsubscribe is structured, it wants it the above format instead of with ?email=.  Can I do this?

EDIT 12/3/13:

Thanks for all the help, guys!  Part of my problem is that I wasn't passing the email var through my generate email function.  :/

Here's how I ended up setting it up:

```
$unsubscribeurl = 'http://example.com/unsubscribe/';

$unsubplus = $unsubscribeurl . $email;

$unsubscribelink = '<a href="' . $unsubplus . '">UNSUBSCRIBE</a>';
```

Then to set the link up, I just used $unsubscribelink.

Comment: Yes, you can. Assuming Apache, read about `mod_rewrite`.

Comment: Do you create the file from .php ? or .html?

Comment: I create the file from php.  The link is part of an echo statement that is creating an email.

Answer (score 0):

Creating the url:

```
$url = 'http://example.com/unsubscribe/' . urlencode($email);
```

Creating the link:

```
$link = '<a href="' . htmlspecialchars($url) . '">link</a>';
```

Using the link in html context:

```
<?php echo $link ?>
```

Or:

```
<a href="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($url) ?>">link</a>
```

[urlencode()](http://php.net/function.urlencode)
[htmlspecialchars()](http://php.net/function.htmlspecialchars.php)

Comment: Hmm, I can't seem to get that working.  The link is appearing in the email like this:

<?php echo htmlspecialchars(http://example.com/unsubscribe/); ?>

I also tried <a href=\"$unsubscribeurl\", but it is making the link just the example.com/unsubscribe, without the var.  My unsubscribeurl var was your 'creating the url' instruction.

Comment: I suspect you're not in html context when you need the link. I've updated my answer accordingly.